# Javascript Event Timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery call event has problem with Timestamp. The first event handler is set to all next. Then it can not be set new event for elements. I use all jquery functions with unbind like off(), live(), on() and etc.

This is console.log() of my first event:

```
> f.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", isDefaultPrevented:
> function, timeStamp: 1385593270116, jQuery172010120543162338436:
> true…}
```

This Event get for next click too!

How can i reset Timestamp with in jquery? or Do you have another way to reload event?

---

Edit: I want to change my element with jquery. When I click on change button, It get an event contexts. My problem is here. This event is set to next clicking too and it can not change my new features.

Comment: I have absolutely no Idea what you are asking. Can you write this down a little bit clearer?

Comment: makes no sense whatsoever to me either....even after edit. Suggest rewrite whole question and provide code for context

Comment: @MarcelGwerder Could i write my mind better?

Comment: You should post a minimal example that displays the issue. It is unclear what your problem is, therefore others can't provide an answer. I think you may be saying that all your events are getting the same "timestamp", which seems to be a javascript Date time value. The one in the OP represents `27 Nov 2013 23:01:10 UTC`.